# YOLO: -bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, cmake, yolo, darknet, yolov4

When I try to train my yolov4 on my vm with command

`./darknet detector train build/darknet/x64/data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-my_gray.cfg backup/yolov4-my_gray_1200.weights -gpus 0,1,2,3 -dont_show`

I received

`-bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory`

Of course I do this in darknet directory. When I try to `make` i received

[image]

When i check open cv

`pkg-config --cflags opencv`

I received

`"-I/usr/include/opencv"`

Maybe somebody can help.

Comment: Please, do NOT post **images** of the code or of the error message. Instead, copy paste them into the question post as **text**.

Answer (score 0):

Seems compiler is not able to find the file in the includes path you mentioned.
First check if `cuda_runtime.h` file is available on your machine and get that location. If the file is available then just give the path of the file to the compiler using `-I` option.
If the file is available at the path `/usr/include/opencv`, then you would need to provide it with `-I` option to the compiler

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/cuda/include ...
```

Comment: When I try
`g++ -std=c++11 - I/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h`

I received 
`g++: fatal error: no input files`

That file exit in usr/local/cuda/include dir

Comment: @Mathew : you should only give the path of the directory where header file is present in this case .Example ``g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/cuda/include/  -o main.o -c main.c ``